# How can I take the article to the left?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website.When I make the page smaller the article is getting below completely while it is normally next to table.I applied float but it did not be enough.How can I fix that?

[image]

Here is the code for html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset = "utf-8">
     <title>Page</title>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "page.css">
   </head>
<header>
</header>
   <body>
       <table border = "2">
         <tr>
             <td><a href="mainpage.html">MAINPAGE</a></td>
         <tr\>
         <tr>
             <td>BLOG</td>
         <tr\>
         <tr>
             <td>CONTACT</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
     <p>
       kajnaldkfgldkfmlgmsdlşngskdgfnşsdjnvfkdsjşfnvsjvnjnknnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
       nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnkjdfnvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvdk
     </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for css:

```
header{
background-image: url("images/logo.jpg") ;width:%100 ;height:250px;margin-top: .2em;padding: .2em;
background-repeat:no-repeat ;background-position:center;
}
body {font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
table{
    border-style: double;
    padding:.2em;
    height:170px;width:240px;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
    table-layout:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    position: relative;
}
tr       {border="5";border-style: solid;margin-top: 2em;}
p  {font-size:1.5em;
       font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
       float:left;
       padding:.2em;
       margin-left:.5em;
       margin-bottom: 50em;
       text-align:left;
       width: 70%;}
```

Comment: don't use table as alyout and correct your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```css
.article {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.article p {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="mainpage.html">MAINPAGE</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BLOG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CONTACT</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    kajnaldkfgldkfmlgmsdlşngskdgfnşsdjnvfkdsjşfnvsjvnjnknnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
    nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnkjdfnvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvdk
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex property

```
.content {
   display: flex;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset = "utf-8">
     <title>Page</title>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "page.css">
   </head>
<header>
</header>
   <body>
   <div class="content">
       <table border = "2">
         <tr>
             <td><a href="mainpage.html">MAINPAGE</a></td>
         <tr\>
         <tr>
             <td>BLOG</td>
         <tr\>
         <tr>
             <td>CONTACT</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
     <p>
       kajnaldkfgldkfmlgmsdlşngskdgfnşsdjnvfkdsjşfnvsjvnjnknnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
       nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnkjdfnvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvdk
     </p>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to write the code in stylesheet but thank you for your answer though@Kunika

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).